# Is it possible to get specific data only from a collection using Java stream?

Tags: java, java-stream

I have the following code:

```
 @Override
      public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        HttpHeaders httpHeaders = Collections.list(httpServletRequest.getHeaderNames())
          .stream()
          .collect(Collectors.toMap(
            Function.identity(),
            h -> Collections.list(httpServletRequest.getHeaders(h)),
            (oldValue, newValue) -> newValue,
            HttpHeaders::new
          ));
        System.out.println(httpHeaders);
          chain.doFilter(request, response);
      }
```

It works just fine, but I would only need to get a few specific data, like accept-encoding and accept language. Is it possible to do that somehow?

Comment: httpServletRequest.getHeader(<header-name>) will get the value of a specific header

Comment: Can you also do two headers at one time?

Comment: what do you want as a result, a map of header name and value or just the values of some headers ?

Comment: Header name and value also, for the specified ones. So basically the code I wrote does that for every data in the header. But I would need the same response, only with a few ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution for this

```
List<String> headerNames = Arrays.asList("Accept-Encoding", "Content-Type");
Map<String, String> headers = headerNames.stream()
     .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), header -> httpServletRequest.getHeader(header)));
```

Or if you want to get HttpHeaders as a result

```
List<String> headers = Arrays.asList("Accept-Encoding", "Content-Type");
HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
headers.forEach(header -> {
    request.getHeaders(header)
             .asIterator()
             .forEachRemaining(value -> httpHeaders.add(header, value));
});
```